Can Apache Camel Postgresql Debezium Component Output Cloud Events
Debezium connectors can be configured to output cloud events instead of the default Struct object. However, when using the Apache Camel PostgreSQL Debezium component with the embedded Debezium engine, I have not been able to successfully configure cloud event exports. I tried to set the internalValueConverter component property to io.debezium.converters.CloudEventsConverter and also tried to set the necessary Debezium properties directly using the additionalProperties map, but I'm still getting Struct objects instead of cloud events. Does anyone know the correct way to configure a Camel Debezium component to output Cloud Events? Thanks!

Apparently, I misread the component documentation. The Camel Debezium components can return a Struct or a Map. From the component doc:

By default, the component will emit the events in the body and
CamelDebeziumBefore header as Struct data type, the reasoning behind this, is to
perceive the schema information in case is needed. However, the component as well
contains a Type Converter that converts from default output type of Struct to Map
in order to leverage Camel’s rich Data Format types which many of them work out
of box with Map data type.

